# My text over system settings screen

Tags: android, android-activity, alert

Good day!

Can somebody give idea, how i can repeat effect such on this screenshot?

[hint over system settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jeh9F.png)

This is a HiLocker, and I need same effect in my application - to open system settings and show my hint.

Thanks.

Comment: My question "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"? OK, more details: I need open the system settings where user can allow my application to intercept notifications. Since it is no way to make it simple for user (big "thanks" to Google for this "usability"), so i need to give a hint, what to do on this system screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here:
http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

You will need a [WindowManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html).

Comment: Big Thanks! This is exactly what i need.